# OpenGL sample one cube map face in a shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

I would like to apply a filter to the OpenGL cube texture. Face by face. How can I sample just one face of the cube map in the shader? I can't use GL_texture_view_ARB, because I have only Opengl 3.3. Can I use sampler2DArray and bind my cube map to assigned unit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you need to create 6 faces of cube map manually, and sample them with different filters. You may need to transform the texture coordinate from a 3D vector to a 2D texcoord for one face, here is the information for doing that: http://www.nvidia.com/object/cube_map_ogl_tutorial.html, please search "Mapping Texture Coordinates to Cube Map Faces" on that web-page.

Comment: So you think, that I have to generate vector, which will be translated to the the required texture coordinates in a specific face?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with OpenGL, so I don't know if there are other methods. But at least, I think this is a way to do it.

Comment: I thought about this option, but I think it is not very effective... Well... Now I know, that I have no other option in OpenGL 3.3 :-). I appreciate your help. I will leave the question opened for while...